# Saving settings for VIM on virtual box

Tags: c++, vim

I am running VIM from SSHing into school's virtual box, but I would like to save my settings for every time I use it.

It's not too much of a pain to type this every time, but I would like to automate it / save it if possible:

```
:set number
:set mouse=a
:set cindent
```

Thanks

Comment: You may also be interested in Vim sessions -- if you're working on a project, you can type `:mks!` to tell Vim to generate a Session file for you. After you exit, you can resume Vim using `vim -S Session.vim`, and the settings from your project (like the buffers you had loaded) will be restored for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit vim local configuration file `~/.vimrc` to insert these lines:

```
set number
set mouse=a
set cindent
```

Comment: ~/.vimrc -- I don't understand what that means or how to implement your advice. Can you explain a bit further? By the way, this is on a shared machine, so I can't modify the VIM everyone has to use. Will this method only affect my VIM?

Comment: ~ means the home directory. Each user that logs into a shared machine should have his own home (just type `echo $HOME` to see what I mean). If you create a `.vimrc` file here the settings will apply only to your user. You can also type `help vimrc` in vim for extra info